# Form input label animation

Tags: jquery, css

I'm building a website with WordPress and using Contact Form 7 as the forms builder.

I want to create a custom animation for the input labels. Without any interaction, the label is inside the input. On focus, the label slides up to let the input clear for the input value. If the input stays empty, on focus out the label slides back again to the original position, otherwise, it remains there.

The motion effect is simple and I've already done it. The problem is the value check, to see if the input it empty or not. This is the jQuery I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var cinput = $('.placeholder-animation input.animate-label');
    var clabel = $('.placeholder-animation span.custom-label');

    cinput.each(function() {
        if(cinput.val() === "") {
            console.log('Up!');
            cinput.focus(function() { clabel.addClass('up'); }).focusout(function() { clabel.removeClass('up'); });
        } else {
            clabel.addClass('up');
            console.log('Always up!');
        }
    });
})
```

What's happening is that even when I write any value in the input and get out of it, the label slides back to the input as if it remains empty. I've tried several solutions all without any positive result...

Help wanted! :) Thanks!

Comment: We'll need a [mcve] but it looks like you remove the up class on the focusout event even when the initial value was empty. You're not checking it again on focusing out.

Comment: Exactly!!! It's working fine now! I check whether the input has value either on focus and focus out. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS3 only.

You will need to put the input inside the label and an span after the input and then use the `:focus` selector:

```
input:focus + span {
 /*label css here*/
}
```

EDIT: here is a pen example: https://codepen.io/MaxViewUp/pen/xrbdxm

if uou are unable to do this only with css (maybe an wrapper arround the field because the plugin), you then can use jQuery to add/remove classes. Then, only add the class selector to the active label

EDIT: you will also need some JS to detect the filled field (until css updates). Check the pen now

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I can't do that because of the plugin, as you said. But the class add and remove is working ok. The problem is when it get out of focus but the input has text. Try that on that pen, if you click outside the input when it has text, the label wi'll still slide down.

Comment: You can add an if on the focus event. the if will test if the imput is empty (or if has an value). Check the pen again

Comment: IE11 doesn't know :focus https://caniuse.com/#search=focus%20css

Comment: @zyrup True, you will need an polyfill (or just ignore IE :D )